# Dynamic textfield disappears when I try to enter text

Tags: actionscript-2

I'm working on an Actionscript 2 project where I want to change the text of a dynamic textfield in a movieclip. However, when I try to change the .text, the textfield becomes blank.

Example code:

```
myInstanceName.text = "Test!";
trace("Run");
```

in a frame. I can confirm the code is being executed, and myInstanceName (a dynamic textfield) turns from whatever text I put there to blank. I have tried using the 'Variable' setting in Properties but this results in the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textfield is probably using embed fonts (configured in Anti-Alias : Anti-alias for animation).

If this is the case, you have two possibilities :

- Select "Use device fonts" : it's less pretty but lighter ; the font will not show correctly if you're not using a usual font
- Click the "Embed" button and select a range of characters you want to use in your textfield